# Removing duplicates from a list of lists in Ocaml?

Tags: list, functional-programming, duplicates, ocaml

I am new to Ocaml, and I am assigned to remove all duplicates of a list of lists using only List module. Here is the code I wrote:

```
let sort_and_remove_duplicates l = 
  let sl = List.sort compare l in
  let rec go l acc = match l with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | [x] -> List.rev (x::acc) 
    | (x1::x2::xs) -> 
      if x1 = x2
      then go (x2::xs) acc
      else go (x2::xs) (x1::acc)
  in go sl []
```

This passes the case for an empty list, but fails for other cases, such as:

```
[[3;1;3]; [4]; [1;2;3]]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by the duplicates of a list of list ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I get when I run your code on what you call the failing case:

```
# sort_and_remove_duplicates [[3;1;3]; [4]; [1;2;3]];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [3; 1; 3]; [4]]
```

This looks like the right answer to me. There are no duplicates in the input list, hence the output list is the same (except sorted).

What answer did you expect for this input?

(As a side comment your code looks extremely good, at least for what I'm thinking it's supposed to do.)